# How do I include HTML bits from another file in a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, include, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet written in jQuery where I'm creating elements and adding them to the DOM.

```
$dot = $('<span class="dot" style="left:0;top:0;" />');
$('body').append($dot);
```

Is there a way I can include HTML without writing it directly in the .js file? The span above is pretty simple, but how can I create a sophisticated form without making it a maintenance nightmare?

**EDIT**

To clarify, I know how to load the script via bookmarklet, but I was wondering if there's any easy way to refrence complex pieces of HTML in the .js file so I don't have long, complex, embedded strings of HTML to maintain inside that one file.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ajax request to load some html data from your server, but be sure to add a cache param to your bookmarklet's script include.

`document.createElement("script");`, add the source, and append it to the current page somewhere (head, body, it's up to you).

EDIT: I may not have been clear enough, but you will want to load the script file from your domain which would then run any ajax requests. Your bookmarklet would then just become a container to test if the dom is ready and append a script (from your server) if so.

Comment: It is worth to mention that the HTML in your server should be a script file, that way all the code will be properly inserted in the ``script`` element created. HTML via AJAX isn't allowed in browsers if source is from a different host.

Comment: I may not have been clear enough either. I know how to load the script via bookmarklet, but I was wondering if there's any easy way to refrence complex pieces of HTML in the .js file so I don't have to have long, complex, embedded strings of HTML to maintain inside that one file.